# Show a convergence in probability using Markov inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $(X)_{j\in \mathbb Z}$ be a discrete random process such that
$$X_{j}= \theta X_{j-1}+ \epsilon_j, \quad (\epsilon_j) \overset{iid}{\sim} N(0,1), |\theta|<1 $$
How to show that

$$P\left(\max_{1\leq j \leq n} |X_j| \geq n^{3/4} \right)\to 0, \quad (n \to \infty)$$

I'm a little unsure about doing the following and I still don't know how to complete it.

$$P\left(\max_{1\leq j \leq n} |X_j| \geq n^{3/4} \right)= P\left(\left[\max_{1\leq j \leq n} |X_j|\right]^2 \geq n^{3/2} \right)\leq \frac{E\left( \left[\max_{1\leq j \leq n} |X_j|\right]^2 \right)}{n^{3/2}}$$

or

$$P\left(\max_{1\leq j \leq n} |X_j| \geq n^{3/4} \right)= P\left(\left[\max_{1\leq j \leq n} |X_j|\right]^2 \geq n^{3/2} \right)= P\left(\max_{1\leq j \leq n} \{|X_j|^2\} \geq n^{3/2} \right) \leq  \frac{E\left( \max_{1\leq j \leq n} \{|X_j|^2\} \right)}{n^{3/2}}$$

In both cases, I use the Markov inequality.

Which alternative is right and how to conclude?

I know that in both cases it would suffice to show that the last Expectation is finite. How to justify this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** My previous approach was flawed, as @Snoop pointed out. I will keep my original "solution" in this answer further below for context. Instead i will detail the approach using Kolmogorov's maximal inequality here:

**Solution:**

Note that the process $X_n$ can be written as $$X_n=\theta X_{n-1}+\epsilon_n=\theta(\theta X_{n-2}+\epsilon_{n-1})+\epsilon_n=\dots=\theta^n X_0+\sum_{i=0}^n \theta^{n-i}\epsilon_i$$
Hence we define the process $$S_n=\sum_{i=0}^n\theta^{n-i}\epsilon_i.$$
As @Karthik P N mentioned, due to the process $S_n$ being a sum of independent random variables, [Kolmogorov's maximal inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_inequality) yields a straightforward approach to bounding the tails of the running maximum of $S_n$. In short, it immediately implies the bound $$\mathbb P\bigg[\max_{i\leq n}|S_i|\geq n^{3/4}\bigg]\leq n^{-3/2}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^n\text{Var}\bigg(\theta^i\epsilon_i\bigg)=n^{-3/2}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^n\theta^{2i}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

**Previous Attempt (which is not quite correct):**

When trying to derive bounds on the maximum of a stochastic process, it is helpful to look for an underlying martingale to then use [Doob's Martingale Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_inequality).

Now the process $$\widetilde S_n:=\sum_{i=0}^n \theta^i \epsilon_i$$ is a square-integrable martingale (**here was my error:** while it is correct that $\widetilde S_n$ is a square-integrable martingale, it is not the same process as $S_n$ defined above. In particular, $S_n$ is **not** a martingale, since $\mathbb E[S_{n+1}|\mathcal F_n]=\theta S_n\neq S_n$).

Note that we have $$\mathbb P\bigg[\max_{i\leq n}|X_i|\geq n^{3/4}\bigg]\leq \mathbb P\bigg[ |X_0|\geq \frac12 n^{3/4}\bigg]+\mathbb P\bigg[\max_{i\leq n}\bigg| \sum_{i=0}^n\theta^i\epsilon_i\bigg|\geq \frac12 n^{3/4}\bigg]$$
Clearly the first summand goes to $0$. For the second summand, we may now use Markov's inequality together with Doob's martingale inequality with $p=2$ to obtain $$\mathbb E\bigg[\max_{i\leq n}\bigg| \sum_{i=0}^n\theta^i\epsilon_i\bigg|^2\bigg]\leq 4\cdot \mathbb E\bigg[\bigg| \sum_{i=0}^n\theta^i\epsilon_i\bigg|^2\bigg]= 4\cdot\sum_{i=0}^n \theta^{2i}$$

Comment: Instead of saying "we may now use Markov's inequality together with Doob's martingale inequality with =2", it may be better to simply state "we may now use Kolmogorov's maximal inequality". Both are equivalent here. The OP may find the latter more easier to read and familiarise with! Just my opinion!

Comment: Very good answer (+1). One thing: it seems to me that the expectation appearing in the middle term in the last inequality is the variance of $S_n$, so the last step is not necessary as the $\epsilon_n$ are iid.

Comment: @KarthikPN You're right. This would have been a bit more straightforward.

Comment: @Snoop Oh, i completely overlooked that. So the last inequality technically is an equlaity, you're right,

Comment: @SmallDeviation but where does that $n$ factor come from? In case you work with the variance, it shouldn't appear if I am not mistaken

Comment: @Snoop You're completely right. The term $n$ shouldn't be there.

Comment: @Snoop Though i am worried that there is no factor involving $n$ appearing anywhere in the final estimate. This would imply that the choice of the sequence $n^{3/4}$ was unnecessary and it could have been any sequence $a_n$ increasing to infinity., no matter how slowly. That doesn't sound right to me, but perhaps the statement is indeed true for any such sequence $a_n$.

Comment: I notice now that there might be a discrepancy: how do we pass from the first line to the definition of $S_n$? It seems the coefficients change from $\theta^{n-i}$ to $\theta^i$ but not the indexes of the epsilon terms? @SmallDeviation

Comment: @Snoop The processes are technically not the same, but they have the same distribution, since the $\epsilon_i$ are i.i.d., so i don't think it should make a difference.

Comment: However, have you checked that if you use the original process, then you obtain a martingale wrt the filtration of the epsilons?

Comment: @Snoop That seems to be the issue. It is **not** a martingale, since we have $\mathbb E[\sum_{i=0}^{n+1}\theta^{n+1-i}\epsilon_i|\mathcal F_n] =\theta \sum_{i=0}^n\theta^{n-i}\epsilon_i$. Therefore my approach using Doob's martingale inequality was flawed. I will fix my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes that could be the issue, but one might expect that a martingale approach could yield the desired result so there is merit in your answer regardless.

Comment: @Snoop Thank you for your helpful remarks. I have edited my answer. Plus, i think i have found a way to make the "martingale approach" work.

Comment: A question has arisen now.  I understood that $X_j = \theta^j X_0 + S_j$ and $|X_j| \leq |\theta^j X_0| + |S_j|$.  Now, I have to take the max: 
$$\max_{1\leq j\leq n}|X_j|  = \max_{1\leq j\leq n} (|\theta^j X_0| + |S_j|) \leq \max_{1\leq j\leq n} |\theta^j X_0| + \max_{1\leq j\leq n} |S_j| = |X_0|\kappa_n + \max_{1\leq j\leq n} |S_j| $$
where $\kappa_n=\max_{1\leq j\leq n} |\theta^j|$. So $P(\max_{1\leq j\leq n}|X_j| \geq n^{3/4}) = P\left(\left\{|X_0|\kappa_n + \max_{1\leq j\leq n} |S_j|\right\}\geq n^{3/4}\right)$.

Comment: In order to conclude, I believe you used: 

$$P\left(\left\{|X_0|\kappa_n + \max_{1\leq j\leq n} |S_j|\right\}\geq n^{3/4}\right)\leq P\left(|X_0|\kappa_n \geq n^{3/4}\right) + P\left(\max_{1\leq j\leq n} |S_j|\geq n^{3/4}\right) $$  That's right?

Comment: @AndréGoulart Yes, almost. Note the factor of $\frac12$ in my expression. If the sum of two numbers $a,b$ is greater than $c$, i.e. $a+b>c$ then at least one of the numbers $a,b$ must be greater than $c/2$, meaning $a>c/2$ or $b>c/2$. Applying this to our setting gives the inequality i had written.

Comment: Perfect. So it would look like this: $P(\max_{1\leq j\leq n}|X_j| \geq n^{3/4}) \leq P\left(|X_0|\kappa_n \geq \frac{1}{2} n^{3/4}\right) + P\left(\max_{1\leq j\leq n} |S_j|\geq \frac{1}{2} n^{3/4}\right)$. However, about the first term we have $P\left(|X_0|\kappa_n \geq \frac{1}{2} n^{3/4}\right)=P\left(|X_0| \geq \frac{n^{3/4}}{2\kappa_n}\right)$
So I'd like to know where $\frac{n^{3/4}}{2\kappa_n}$ would have to go so that the first term converges to zero. Thank you for the patience.

Comment: @AndréGoulart Just note that $\kappa_n=|\theta|$. Then clearly the term $n^{3/4}/\kappa_n\to\infty$ hence the probability goes to $0$.

Comment: Yes, it was obvious. It was my lack of attention. I believe this is true for any $a_n \to \infty$.