# An exercise on convergences involving a fixed realization of a stochastic process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $(X_j)_{j\in \mathbb Z}$ be an strictly stationary and ergodic process with:
$$E[X_j]=0, \quad E[X_j]^2 < \infty$$
I am traying to show  the following:

Let $(\bar{X}_j)_{j \in \mathbb Z}$ be a fixed realization of $(X_j)_{j\in \mathbb Z}$. Denote $a_n=\frac{b(n - b)}{n^2}$, with $b >0$. So, we have:
\begin{equation}\label{1}\tag{I}
\max_{1\leq j \leq n}\left\{ \sqrt{a_n} \, |\bar{X}_j|\right\} \to 0, \quad (n \to \infty)
\end{equation}

The justification my teacher gave was: by the tail behavior, i.e., second moments of $(\bar{X}_j)_{j \in \mathbb Z}$, we can show that:
\begin{equation}\label{2}\tag{II}
P\left[\max_{1\leq j \leq n} |\bar{X}_j| \geq n^{3/4}\right]\to 0, \quad(n \to \infty)
\end{equation}

So, I have two questions:

1. How to show (\ref{2})?
   A little earlier, I asked a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4719248/show-a-convergence-in-probability-using-markov-inequality) for a particular case. But I couldn't adapt it to the more general case.
2. Once (\ref{2}) shown. How to show that (\ref{2}) implies (\ref{1})?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that (II) should be rewritten with $\overline{X_j}$ replaced by $X_j$.

One needs an almost sure convergence, so I fail to see how a corrected version of (II) would give information on a realisation.

It is possible to show that $\max_{1\leq j\leq n}\lvert X_j\rvert/\sqrt n\to 0$ almost surely. Indeed,  $\max_{1\leq j\leq n}\lvert X_j\rvert/\sqrt n\to 0$ almost surely is equivalent to $2^{-n/2}\max_{1\leq j\leq 2^n}\lvert X_j\rvert \to 0$ almost surely and in view of the Borel-Cantelli lemma, it suffices to show that for each positive $\varepsilon$,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P\left(\max_{1\leq j\leq 2^n}\lvert X_j\rvert>2^{n/2}\varepsilon\right)<\infty.
$$
This follows from a union bound and square integrability of $X_1$.

Once we have the almost sure convergence, (I) holds for almost every realisations because $\sqrt{a_n}$ behaves like $1/\sqrt n$.

Comment: Dear Davide, thanks for the answer. Following your suggestion, I think I concluded: Note that $$\mathbb P\left(\max_{1\leq j\leq 2^n}\lvert X_j\rvert>2^{n/2}\varepsilon\right)=\mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{2^n}\left[\lvert X_j\rvert>2^{n/2}\varepsilon\right]\right)\leq \sum_{j=1}^{2^n}\mathbb P\left(\lvert X_j\rvert>2^{n/2}\varepsilon\right)$$
By stationarity, we have 
$$\mathbb P\left(\max_{1\leq j\leq 2^n}\lvert X_j\rvert>2^{n/2}\varepsilon\right)\leq 2^n \,\, \mathbb P\left(\lvert X_1\rvert>2^{n/2}\varepsilon \right)=2^n \,\, \mathbb P\left( \lvert X_1\rvert^2>2^n \varepsilon^2 \right)$$

Comment: By Markov's inequality: 
$$2^n \,\, \mathbb P\left( \lvert X_1\rvert^2>2^n \varepsilon^2 \right) \leq 2^n \, \,  \frac{\mathbb E[\, |X_1|^2\,]}{2^n \epsilon^2} = \frac{\mathbb E[\, |X_1|^2\,]}{ \epsilon^2} $$
Is this right?

Comment: I agree with your first comment. However, your approach in the second one only gives a uniform bound over $n$, while you need the convergence of the series. Decompose the event $\{X_1^2>2^n\epsilon^2\}$ as the disjoint union $\bigcup_{k\geq n}\{2^k\epsilon^2<X_1^2\leq 2^{k+1}\epsilon\}$.